# Add Heartbeat API's filter in plugin - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to receive a custom value from a request made by WordPress Heartbeat API.
The problem is that the filter only work in functions.php and not from plugin constructor as I always do.

I have plenty others hooks which perfectly work. The syntax is correct. Can I misunderstand the loading sequence ?

In plugin constructor (don't work):

```
add_filter( 'heartbeat_received', array( $this, 'test_heartbeat_received' ), 10, 2 );

function test_heartbeat_received( $response, $data ) {
    $response['test'] = 'test';
    return $response;
}
```

In functions.php (work):

```
add_filter( 'heartbeat_received', 'test_heartbeat_received', 10, 2 );

function test_heartbeat_received( $response, $data ) {
    $response['test'] = 'test';
    return $response;
}
```

I expect this JSON response : { test: "test", "wp-auth-check": true, server_time: 1546856046 }, 
but only get { "wp-auth-check": true, server_time: 1546856046 }.

Thank you for your help !

**EDIT**

I have managed to make it work by putting the filter outside the main class, the problem could be in relation with POO but I don't understand the process...

```
add_filter( 'heartbeat_received', array(  new Test, 'test_heartbeat_received' ), 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Try to change the filter priority to 1

Comment: I have tried with no success.

Answer (score 1):

My class, related to front page, was instantiated with the conditionnal tag `!is_admin()` so all AJAX actions were not triggered. Without this condition it works !